# How to convert date format from ("2014-12-24") to ("3/24/2014")

Tags: javascript

I've an input text box with value ("2014-12-24"),I want to convert to ("3/24/2014"), So how to convert the date format in javaScript? Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at [DateJS](www.datejs.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below two ways to change the format as desired-

**First:**

```
    var originalFormat = new Date('2014-12-24');
    var newFormat = (originalFormat.getMonth() + 1)+'-'+originalFormat.getDate()+'-'+originalFormat.getFullYear();
    alert(newFormat);
```

**Fiddle Url:** http://jsfiddle.net/omdk18Lx/2/

**Second:**

Use this library-
https://github.com/jacwright/date.format

See its usage- http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/

Answer (score 0):

You could look at .split() and split the string on '-'

```
var oldDate = "2014-12-24";
var arrDate = oldDate.split('-');
//arrDate has three elements (y, m, d)
var newDate = arrDate[1]+'/'+arrDate[2]+'/'+arrDate[0];
//newDate = 12/24/2014
```